# Keyboard doesn't appear automatically when using AutocompleteFragment or AutocompleteActivity in API 28

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

As of a few weeks ago, I've noticed that the soft keyboard doesn't appear automatically when opening an AutocompleteFragment or AutocompleteActivity. Instead, the user has to tap the search bar at the top This behavior is only seen in API 28.

Is there anything I can do to change this behavior? Or is this a bug that Google will soon fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've officially submitted this as a bug and it was accepted:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124740771